# An error occurred: Cannot run program "C:\Users\ford\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied

Tags: python, jsp

I'm encountering a problem while trying to call a Python program from a JSP (JavaServer Pages) file. Despite ensuring that the Python script (careerbook_refyx.py) has appropriate read and execute permissions for the user account, and confirming that the file path to the .py file is correct, the execution is failing.

Here's what I've already tried:

Checked permissions: Confirmed that careerbook_refyx.py has appropriate read and execute permissions for the user account.
Verified file path: Ensured that the file path to the Python script is correct.
Multiple Python installations: Acknowledged having multiple python.exe files on my system.
Attempted explicit path specification: Tried explicitly specifying the path to the Python executable in the JSP file, but the issue persists.
I'm unsure how to proceed further to resolve this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The question is not about specifically to programming but a permission giving requester. Should be managed on the admin site.